# Картинки слайдера скачут

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день!

Возникла проблема: делаю прокрутку слайдера на основе библиотеки [jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js](http://pcvector.net/scripts/slideshow_and_scroller/407-smooth-div-scroll-gorizontalnaya-prokrutka-kontenta.html). Фреймворк jquery-1.8.3.min.js. Слайдер первый шаг делает правильно, потом начинает скакать, прокручивая дважды картинки. Общая длина всех картинок, включенных в слайдер, составляет 1500 пикселей вместе с отступами между картинками. Шаг составляет 490 пикселей (чему, собственно, и равна длина каждой картинки). Пишу такой код:

```
 el.data("scrollingHotSpotRight").bind("click", function () {

 var RightPos = el.data("scrollWrapper").scrollLeft() + 490;
 el.data("scrollWrapper").animate({"scrollLeft": RightPos}, "slow");
 console.log("RightPos: "+RightPos);               
 console.log("scrollLeft: "+el.data("scrollWrapper").scrollLeft());            
});
```

scrollWrapper - это div-блок слайдера. Консоль выдает такие значения:

> RightPos: 490
> scrollLeft: 0
>
> RightPos: 980
> scrollLeft: 490
>
> RightPos: 964
> scrollLeft: 474
>
> RightPos: 948
> scrollLeft: 458

Как понять такую логику изменения этих переменных? 
А когда пишу вместо animate такой код:

```
el.data("scrollWrapper").scrollLeft(RightPos);
```

То слайдер листает нормально картинки, только без анимации. Как понять такую особенность? Что такого особенного в анимации? Если не знаете решения, может, посоветуете, как реализовать плавное передвижение слайдов, минуя злополучный метод animate? Буду благодарен за советы...

Comment: Предложите альтернативу метода animate, чтобы была плавная прокрутка, но без таких глупых глюков.

Comment: Похоже, никто предложить идею решения этой проблемы так и не смог...